# Not able to login to Salesforce application through JMeter

Tags: jmeter, salesforce, force.com

Not able to login into Salesforce Application through JMeter.

Please help.

I am providing correct Username and Password but still not able to login successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that with username and password only it will not work. You need to correlate all the dynamic value which maintains the state of the application like sessionID, X-CSRF token etc. 
So, record two scripts and compare the dynamic parameters and then correlate them.
For more information on correlation please check [this.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) and [correlation sales force.](http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2017/06/29/jmeter-logging-salesforce/)

Comment: I am using all the required form data and HTTP Headers, but still User is not getting Logged in into application through Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Have you added HTTP Cookie Manager in your jmeter script? If not, can you add it and then give it another shot?

Comment: Yes have added HTTP Cookie Manager and
I am using all the required form data and HTTP Headers, but still User is not getting Logged in into application through Jmeter

Comment: It would be better to investigate this further if you post some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

A login HTTP Request will not work, you need to authenticate with network login by adding Port, proxy details and all.
If that doesn't help then you can try ["BlazeMeter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en)" plugin, install this extension in Chrome browser and record your steps, it will then convert your inputs into a JMX file, there you can see which steps need to be added and modify accordingly. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs.
I have recorded scripted using BlazeMeter extension in chrome. But, when i run this script in JMeter the login functionality fails.

Could you please let me know how to achieve the first solution which you mentioned i.e.
"need to authenticate with network login by adding Port, proxy details and all"

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay in response. Go to "HTTP Request Defaults" click on "Advance" tab and their you need to add Port Proxy details to access secured HTPPS links. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mad Einsy.
i am not aware of what Port Proxy details i am suppose to mention under the 'Proxy Server' section in the HTTP Request Defaults element.

Could you please let me know what exact details i need to put.